# Segmentation Fault in vector<vector<string>>

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting segmentation fault in this piece of code?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<vector<string> > v;
    v[0].push_back("good");
    
    cout<<v[0][0];

}
```

I am trying to insert the string "good" in the first vector, and I am trying to access that by `v[0][0]`, but it is giving me `segmentation fault`. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You vector is empty. `v[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Obligatory avoid `using namespace std;` ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) and do not use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) comment. Separately they are bad, but when you put them together, they magnify each other's worst effects and turn the program into a minefield of unused identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The inner vector starts out with 0 elements, you push 1 element and then you can access the first via `[0]`. That's fine.

However, the outer vector works the same way: You first need to add an element before you can access it.

Either call the constructor that lets you specify the size:

```
vector<vector<string> > v(1);
v[0].push_back("good");
```

or push the element:

```
vector<vector<string> > v;
vector<string> w;
w.push_back("good");
v.push_back(w);
```

Comment: Thanks... :)
But why largest prime is 463035818? XD